# How to copy Site Data from One Environment to another in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay-6

I want to import the sites and site related data from Dev environment to Local. I was wondering if I can just copy some of the Liferay DB tables into my Local environment and will get the same site and data in my local. I have tried importing the site with .lar import and export through Control Panel but it doesn't work as the lar import export has some bugs in Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2 (the environment that we are using). Is this as straight forward as copying the tables or Are there more steps involved? Is Data folder in Liferay_home involved in this process? Do I have to copy the Data from? I do have an existing Liferay schema in Local which I don't care if it gets over-ridden.

Answer (score 1):

With the keyword "*some*", the answer is: OMG, No! (read the "in general" paragraph for justification of the amplification)

If you want to *completely* move one environment to the other, the approach indeed works. I call it [backup/restore](https://dev.liferay.com/de/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/backing-up-a-liferay-installation), but it's an *all-or-nothing* approach, and indeed it involves the document library, which by default is located in `${liferay.home}`, unless you changed that default. It *might* also involve the search index, unless you want to reindex after restoring.

As a side-benefit this process will easily test your backup strategy and prove that you can use this data to restore on a completely new environment.

And, in general: You should *never ever* consider writing to *any* of Liferay's tables through other means than the Liferay API. This is known to have missed so many interdependencies that it will cause problems later. It *might* work right now, but imagine that you'd like to upgrade your installation one day - if the upgrade routines expect data that you don't have, you'll curse about the idea to write to the tables then - it might require a complete new setup if your upgrade fails then.

Side note: 6.1.1 was [released](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/) in February 2013, the last update to 6.1.x, 6.1.2, is from December 2013. If you know of issues in 6.1.1, you might want to try if they've been fixed in 6.1.2, or in 6.2.x, or 7.0.x - and you should really go with a more current version sooner rather than later, not only because of the one issue you already know.

Comment: That's why I was asking for **all** the tables that are sites related. But as I was reading your answer, I realized that those tables might have the user information of the user who created them too and probably some other information that I don't realize right now. I am using Liferay 7 for newer projects but there is an existing project that runs on Liferay 6.1 which can't be upgraded right now because of the priority of things. Anyways, thanks for sharing your wisdom as always Olaf!